# $\sum^{\infty}_{n=m}a_n^2\rightarrow 0$ if $m\rightarrow \infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I know that $\displaystyle\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}a_n^2<\infty$. It is intuitive for me think that $\displaystyle\sum^{\infty}_{n=m}a_n^2\rightarrow 0$ if $m\rightarrow \infty$, but I fail to prove this rigorously. Can you help me with this? I have been thinking alot about this. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

If $\sum\limits_{n = 0}^{\infty} a_n^2 < \infty$, then the sequence of partial sums $S_N = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^{N} a_n^2$ necessarily has a finite limit $L$. Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given and choose $N$ large enough such that whenever $k \ge N$, it is true that $|S_k - L| < \epsilon$.

But $|S_k - L| = \sum\limits_{n = k+1}^{\infty} a_n^2$, so the answer is yes.

Comment: This is clear. Thanks!

Comment: I think that you mean $S_N = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{N} a_n^2$ ?

Comment: @Cortizol Yes, thank you.